# Facebook automation via PowerShell?

Tags: facebook, powershell

Can anyone provide a link to a PowerShell module which provides automation support for Facebook?  I want to do a project for a nonprofit in this area, and don't want to have to go straight to OAth etc.

This is related to 2598453, but I'm looking more for automation to access friend lists, posting lists etc.

[How do I automate navigation to a website that requires authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598453/how-do-i-automate-navigation-to-a-website-that-requires-authentication)

Thanks,  Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShellPowerBook is OK, but it's based on the deprecated REST API. I have created a new module, currently in Technology Preview. Try http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com, and let me know how this works for you!

Comment: Now in Alpha ... check it out!

Comment: FacebookPSModule is now in Alpha

Answer (score 2):

Check this Facebook PowerShell module: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPowerBook

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying to make use of this. The basic functionality seems OK, however it uses the deprecated FaceBook C# SDK 3.0.x, and some functionality such as Get-FBEvent doesn't seem to work. I am working on using the new 5.0.x API but still fighting with the authentication layer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!  It's in alpha, undergoing active development (as of October 2011).

http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com/