# Copying facebook posts/notes to SharePoint intranet

Tags: facebook, sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

My company has a facebook page and posts 'notes' with pictures and updates on the company. For security, we've blocked facebook, so I'd like to copy those facebook posts to our internal SharePoint, either a list, blog site or something similar.

I've looked at using RSS Viewer Web Part & Facebook Graph API, but seems like the user/client would still need access to facebook (not just the server).

I'm not a programmer but could use PowerShell or another scripting language. I'm looking for ideas on how to accomplish copying facebook data to SharePoint on a regular basis. I considered ifttt.com as well but i'm not comfortable giving it my userid/password to SharePoint.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4686438/763026 - Might help you

Answer (score 0):

If you calling Facebook graph api from inside Javascript you should give access to client machine as well. You can use Server side code(ASP .Net) to connect with Facebook api and call that from JavaScript. I think problem here because of different between client side and server side scripting. Thanks

Comment: As I seen other place your application may use iframe tag to call facebook api. Use ASP script to call facebook api and call that script form iframe tag.